# Building grep command string with OR option inside python

Tags: python, regex, linux, escaping

I need to execute

```
grep 'ERROR:A:\|ERROR:B:\|ERROR:C:\|RESOLVED:A:\|RESOLVED:B:\|RESOLVED:C:' /HOME/SOME_LOCATION/FILENAME
```

This works fine in shell, but I need to excute it from my python script.
So in the python script I do

```
filename = "/HOME/SOME_LOCATION/FILENAME"
cmd = 'grep \'ERROR:A:\|ERROR:B:\|ERROR:C:\|RESOLVED:A:\|RESOLVED:B:\|RESOLVED:C:\' '+filename+''
```

But if I give it to

```
commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
```

it gives error

```
     commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

I tried to find what cmd had, strangely it was

```
>"grep 'ERROR:A:\\|ERROR:B:\\|ERROR:C:\\|RESOLVED:A:\\|RESOLVED:B:\\|RESOLVED:C: /HOME/SOME_LOCATION/FILENAME"
```

1. Now it puts 2 Esc sequence backslashes, which I dont understand why. Also , I'm assuming this to be the reason why commands.getstatusoutput did not work.

Is there any way to make this command work.

This is just a part of my bigger objective, I also need to use get a count of matching strings using grep -c, check it with previous grep count (which I would save in some variable) and using the difference, print last such lines. eg. if grep -c 'exp' file gives 15 and the previous count was 10 (meaning 5 new entries have been appended) I need to print those 5. However I'm currently stuck at the beginning itself.

Python 2.5

Comment: Tried removing the escape sequence used for OR in grep, In the assupmtion that python is anyhow putting backslash, but now it doesnt put any backslash at all.
cmd = 'grep \'ERROR:A:|ERROR:B:|ERROR:C:|RESOLVED:A:|RESOLVED:B:|RESOLVED:C:\' '+filename+''
In this case cmd is

Comment: cmd = 'grep "ERROR:A:\|ERROR:B:\|ERROR:C:\|RESOLVED:A:\|RESOLVED:B:\|RESOLVED:C:\" '+filename+'' ............... tried this with subprocess.Popen with shell=True option.It was working fine.

Comment: The error message **very clearly** shows that the problem is **nothing to do with** the quoting, the value of `cmd` or anything else like that: the reported problem is that you typed **a space in front of** the `commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)` code at the REPL, which is indeed an "unexpected indent" exactly as it says.

Answer (score -1):

its about the single quote.

The escaped single quote just infront of `\'ERROR` is creating the problem I think
change it to double quote and it will work:

```
>>> import commands
>>> filename = '/home/rituraj/codetosuccess.txt' 
>>> cmd = 'grep \"ERROR:A:\\|ERROR:B:\\|ERROR:C:\\|RESOLVED:A:\\|RESOLVED:B:\\|RESOLVED:C:\" '+filename
>>> commands.getstatusoutput(cmd)
(0, 'ERROR:A:\\|ERROR:B:\\|ERROR:C:\\|RESOLVED:A:\\|RESOLVED:B:\\|RESOLVED:C:')
```

Comment: >>> cmd4 = 'grep \"ERROR:A:\\|ERROR:B:\\|ERROR:C:\\|RESOLVED:A:\\|RESOLVED:B:\\|RESOLVED:C:\" '+filename
>>> cmd4
'grep "ERROR:A:\\|ERROR:B:\\|ERROR:C:\\|RESOLVED:A:\\|RESOLVED:B:\\|RESOLVED:C:" /home/path/filename.log'
>>>  commands.getstatusoutput(cmd4)
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    commands.getstatusoutput(cmd4)
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

Answer (score -1):

I used

```
cmd = """grep \'ERROR:A:\|ERROR:B:\|ERROR:C:\|RESOLVED:A:\|RESOLVED:B:\|RESOLVED:C:\''+filename+''
```

And then it would show

```
>>>cmd
"grep 'ERROR:negativeSpread:\\|ERROR:mktdataLimit:\\|ERROR:instNoData:\\|RESOLVED:negativeSpread:\\|RESOLVED:mktdataLimit:\\|RESOLVED:instNoData:' /home/trading/chaya/logs/today/20140730.latency.log"
>>> print cmd
grep 'ERROR:negativeSpread:\|ERROR:mktdataLimit:\|ERROR:instNoData:\|RESOLVED:negativeSpread:\|RESOLVED:mktdataLimit:\|RESOLVED:instNoData:' /home/trading/chaya/logs/today/20140730.latency.log
>>> commands.getstatusoutput(cmd1)
```

works absolutely fine.

So this is somewhat a misnomer still and I got this understanding from a post on stackoverflow (cant post the link, since I need 15 reputation)

Thanks All